# syntax error mysql (order by length)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting a syntax error with this particular statement, i have gone true the statement and checked for mistakes and cannot seem to find any, perhaps a fresh pair of eyes might see something.

```
SELECT Purchase_Order.Airline_Carrier_Code, 
       Aircraft_Purchased.*, 
       Aircraft.Unit_Price * Aircraft_Purchased.Quantity as Total_Cost 
  FROM Aircraft_Purchased 
 INNER JOIN Purchase_Order ON Aircraft_Purchased.Order_Number = Purchase_Order.Order_Number 
  INNER JOIN Aircraft_Purchased.Aircraft_ID = Aircraft.Aircraft_ID 
ORDER BY (Purchase_Order.Airline_Carrier_Code), Purchase_Order.Airline_Carrier_Code;
```

The error code i receive is below

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Aircraft_ID ORDER BY LENGTH(Purchase_Order.Airline_Carrier_Code), Purchase_Orde' at line 1****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `Aircraft` table reference after the second `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT purchase_order.airline_carrier_code, 
       aircraft_purchased.*, 
       aircraft.unit_price * aircraft_purchased.quantity AS Total_Cost 
FROM   aircraft_purchased 
       INNER JOIN purchase_order 
               ON aircraft_purchased.order_number = purchase_order.order_number 
       INNER JOIN aircraft  <--- here
               ON aircraft_purchased.aircraft_id = aircraft.aircraft_id 
ORDER  BY purchase_order.airline_carrier_code;
```

Comment: thank you, i knew it was something simple

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN Aircraft_Purchased.Aircraft_ID=Aircraft.Aircraft_ID ORDER BY

INNER JOIN `table name`, and ON section.